# Which hoster support JSP?

Tags: jsp, web, server, hosting, web-hosting

i'm from Switzerland. I developed on behalf of the student councils a web application which uses JSP. Now I should find a suitable hoster. But the common swiss hoster do not support JSP. So I'm looking for alternative hosts. The hoster shouldn't be too expensive. The application is very small and hasn't much functions. There is a fileupload. I except visitor with a maximum of 100 at the same time and 200 fileuploads per month. So a very small server with less traffic is enough. But there should be a limit, so that costs cant explode. Can you recommend me a hoster which support JSP/Tomcat?

Friends told me that Google Cloud is really good and cheap. But the big range of offers overstrained me. I don't know, which products I have to look at.

My english isn't that good, so probably a hoster which supports german wouldn't be that bad. But this isn't a must-have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon AWS service has an option for free for 12 months.
[Amazon aws free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/)

It is basically a cloud server that you can install tomcat and java on. The spec for this server is good enough for basic jsp+tomcat+mysql work.

Comment: thank you ... at least there is always a stupid member which clicks downvote ... sry, can't upvote u

Comment: @sven_meye_97 it's alright, lm glad to know what your final choice of cloud service is.